# Property XXXX is not multi-line exception in python GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a simple model object with

```
profilename = db.StringProperty()
```

and when I get a string with "Some More" and try to

> put

it in model
it throws exception

> Property profilename is not multi-line

Is space equivalent to newline or I have missed something here? It is

> put ting

for single word strings without spaces.

Comment: Is there any chance that the "Some More" string is actually "Some More\n"? You might not be able to see the newline, but it could still be there.

Comment: no it does not have new line and in fact it is extracted from a larger string so there is very little chance of newline coming through

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The check's being done at application level, specifically in StringProperty.validate -- the code in question (which you can find in your SDK's sources in ext/db/**init**.py) is:

```
if not self.multiline and value and value.find('\n') != -1:
  raise BadValueError('Property %s is not multi-line' % self.name)
```

so there's no way it can be triggered unless a `\n` **has** indeed found its way into the `value` you're passing in.  To help you debug the issue, use

```
logging.info('value is: %r', value)
```

just before the `put` that's giving you problems -- what do you see in the logs as a result?  The `%r` format specifier shows the `repr` of your string, so you'll be able to observe where's the pesky `\n` that shouldn't ever be there, and, from that info, debug the issue.

Comment: strangely if I change stringproperty attribute multiline=true it does not complain. Thx for the input though, I will check again and see.

Comment: @dhaval, of course it won't complain about newlines for a multiline string property -- that's what it being multiline is _about_;-).